# Take HD screenshots of YouTube videos

Tags: youtube, images, screenshot

How do I get HD quality screenshots of YouTube videos?

I  want a better alternative to the printscreen-copy-paste method.

The service http://youtubescreenshot.com/ does not provide HD images consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other local screenshot tools like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) to directly directly make HD screenshots.